# Getting GoogleJsonResponseException but the query is properly built in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to build a custom formula for a Google Sheets spreadsheet. Using Google Apps Script, I'm trying to access the Unique Event Count of an event, with a specific Event Label in a Google Analytics view. Here is my code below:

```
function USE_CLICK_COUNT(startDate, endDate){
  var tableId = 'ga:78467590';
  var reportStart = startDate;
  var reportEnd = endDate;
  var optArgs = {
    'metrics': 'ga:uniqueEvents',
    'dimensions':'ga:eventLabel',
    'filters':'ga:eventLabel=~^UseClick'
  };
  
  var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, '2020-08-31', '2020-09-06', optArgs);
  Logger.log(results);
}
```

Although this is not the final version of the function, I tested it to see if it works so far. However I get the following error:

> GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to analytics.data.ga.get failed
> with error: Invalid value '{metrics=ga:uniqueEvents,
> dimensions=ga:eventLabel, filters=ga:eventLabel=~^UseClick}'. Values
> must match the following regular expression: 'ga:.+' (line 16, file
> "Code")

I tried changing the capitalization of Analytics query args, but nothing changed. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- The arguments of `Analytics.Data.Ga.get` are `ids, start-date, end-date, metrics, optionalArgs`. So in your script, `metrics` is not set. I think that this might be the reason of your issue. So please set `metrics`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=en#metrics) Although I'm not sure what you want, for example, as a test, how about testing it by setting `ga:pageviews` as `metrics`.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, '2020-08-31', '2020-09-06', optArgs);
```

To:

```
var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, '2020-08-31', '2020-09-06', "ga:pageviews", optArgs);
```

#### Note:

- It seems that `var results = Analytics.Data.Ga.get(tableId, '2020-08-31', '2020-09-06', "", optArgs);` occurs no error.

#### References:

- [Core Reporting API - Reference Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=en)
- [metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference?hl=en#metrics)

Comment: Oh, okay this worked. I missed the point that metrics is a required argument for Analytics.Data.Ga.get(). Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @mert dökümcü Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.